# Android Font Kerning: Nexus 7 vs. Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, fonts, android-4.2-jelly-bean, kerning

I'm currently developing an application that was originally meant to be run solely on Nexus 7 and Android 4.2. However, there was a change of plans and now it is meant to run on the Galaxy Tab 2, Android 4.1.1 instead.

I am using a custom font that rendered great on the Nexus 7. However, when downgrading the version of Android and switching to the Galaxy Tab 2, the font kerning got completely messed up and looks terrible. Spacing is way off from what it should be.

Any tips to point me in the right direction for fixing this issue? I don't have the slightest idea how to fix this, except for switching to a different font, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Yes, text does look a bit different in Android 4.2](http://www.androidcentral.com/yes-text-does-look-bit-different-android-42)

Comment: That is an interesting article.  I will keep that in mind in my hunt for a solution, but that worries me that the best solution will end up being "pick a font that minimizes Android 4.1's bad kerning" :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have run across the kerning problem described here: [Android Custom View code stopped working correctly in Jelly Bean 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405132/android-custom-view-code-stopped-working-correctly-in-jelly-bean-4-2/14635792#14635792)

It is possible to work around it.