# Different output in Android 4.1

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I've run my program on Android 2.3 and Android 4.1 but pictures of my app shown very tiny in android 4.1:

[image]

I remove `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />` in `manifest.xml`
and my app work perfectly on both:

[image]

but I dont want to remove `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />`

Where is my problem?

abstract of my code is:

```
public class MapCanvas extends ImageView
{    
    ...

    public MapCanvas(Context context) 
    {
        super(context); 
    }

    public MapCanvas(MainActivity context, Bundle state) 
    {
        super(context);                 

        this.context = context; 

        ... 
    }               

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {                               
        super.onDraw(canvas);               

        ...

        //Paint Offset X, Y, Zoom
        this.paint.setColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 51)); 
        this.paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        this.paint.setTextSize(15);
        String text = "X:" + OFFSET_X + ", Y:" + OFFSET_Y + ", Zoom:" + MapZoom.Zoom;                                                     
        canvas.drawText(text, 5, 15, paint);  

        ...       
    }

    ...     
}
```

Comment: +1 because an image always worths a thousand words!

Comment: Are screen resolution/dpi/size the same for both?

Comment: @Seraphim yes__________________________

Comment: Can you post the layout.xml you use?

Comment: @Seraphim i am using canvas for draw image and i havent layout.xml

Comment: Do you use a Custom control that extends View object? Can you post the code used to draw on canvas?

Comment: @Seraphim yes, please see my edit above

Comment: Is the problem on drawText()?

Comment: @Seraphim yes, draw text and draw image too

Comment: I faced a similar issue for drawText() look my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941270/android-4-2-on-nexus-7-canvas-drawtext-not-working-correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing `targetSdkVersion` makes it implicitly `1`, enabling all backwards compatibility modes, including [UI scaling for apps targeting below API level 4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT). That explains why removing the `uses-sdk` "fixes" the problem.

To fix your code, you will have to [scale your pixel sizes and measures with screen density](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android).

Comment: i removed targetSdkVersion, but it dosent work.my pictures are in asset folder.

Comment: Of course single-resolution image in assets will look smaller on a higher-density display. So, edit the question and show how you are decoding/scaling the images.

Comment: what about 2 picture of android 4.1. i just remove <use-sdk ... /> and everything work perfectly.

Comment: I've explained that in the first paragraph. It's not perfect, rather an upscaled compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot friends

I edited `<use-sdk ... />` to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="1" />
```

and added `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` to above of `MapCanvas`

my problem solved!

Comment: This is an awful "solution". You should use actual min/target values for SDK versions in manifest and scale any "dp" values in code to screen pixel values based on density. The question I linked in my answer has some pointers towards that.