# drawText in android using canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I am using following code.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyView (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyView (final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        final float scale = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        canvas.translate((scale == getHeight()) ? ((getWidth() - scale) / 2) / scale : 0
                , (scale == getWidth()) ? ((getHeight() - scale) / 2) / scale : 0);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setTextSize(0.5f);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        //paint.setLinearText(true);
        canvas.drawText("Low", 1f, 0f, paint);
    }
}
```

This code prints only `L` [first character] instead of full string, So I searched google and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941270/android-4-2-on-nexus-7-canvas-drawtext-not-working-correctly/13971632#13971632) answer. But while I am trying this nothing is shown. Any help will be highly appreciable.

I am using `Lollipop`

Comment: My be you are drawing something on top of it afterwards. Just try this in a standalone app, I think it should work just fine.

Comment: This is the complete code.

Comment: Try giving bounds(Rect) to the text